# instantapp:checkReleaseLibraries Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps, android-module

Got gradle error when build my instant app project.

```
Features [:feature1, :feature1] all package the same library [com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava].

Features [:feature1, :feature1] all package the same library [reviews_lib::release].
```

and so on.. All these libraries uses in future1 and in future2, but not added to base module.

Before it used to work fine. I don't know what exactly broke it.

Comment: can you check URl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification  , https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: What changes did you make that made it suddenly stop working?

Comment: can you show your gradle dependencies for your modules?

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787